# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;org.springframework.orm.hibernate4

Tags: spring, hibernate

When i try to integrate my web maven project with spring4.2.2release and hibernate4.2.0Final，I got the array below:

`严重: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/ismdhust] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.openSession(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:204)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1368)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

I have searched a lot and most of them says the reason is the conflict of version between spring and hibernate. 
Could anybody give me a hand? Thanks!!!!!
Here is my configuration below:
1.pom.xml:

```html
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.10.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>${mysql.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>${mockito.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.7</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
    <version>${unitils.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-testng</artifactId>
    <version>${unitils.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${unitils.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${unitils.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-database</artifactId>
    <version>${unitils.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-dbmaintainer</artifactId>
    <version>${unitils.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>${unitils.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>${aopalliance.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
    <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.25</version>
      <configuration>
        <connectors>
          <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <port>80</port>
            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
          </connector>
        </connectors>
        <contextPath>/forum</contextPath>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
  <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
  <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
  <aspectj.version>1.8.1</aspectj.version>
  <aopalliance.version>1.0</aopalliance.version>
  <mysql.version>5.1.29</mysql.version>
  <servlet.version>3.0-alpha-1</servlet.version>
  <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
  <jetty.version>8.1.8.v20121106</jetty.version>
  <aspectjweaver.version>1.6.8</aspectjweaver.version>
  <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
  <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
  <unitils.version>3.4.2</unitils.version>
  <selenium.version>2.41.0</selenium.version>
  <dbunit.version>2.5.1</dbunit.version>
  <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
</properties>
```

2.part of web.xml:

```html
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
    <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name> flushMode </param-name>
    <param-value>AUTO </param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

3.part of applicationContext.xml:

```html
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<bean id="dataSource" 
   class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
   destroy-method="close" 
   p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" 
   p:url="${jdbc.url}" 
   p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
   p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"   
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" 
   p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" 
   p:mappingDirectoryLocations="classpath:/com/ismd/domain/hbm">

  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
      </prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
  <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="create*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" />
    <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" />
    <tx:method name="reg*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" />
    <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" />
    <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" />
    <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" />
  </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
  <aop:advisor id="managerTX" advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="execution(* com.ismd.*.*(..))" order="1" />
</aop:config>
```

4.In pom.xml, by ctrl+shift+t and search org.springframework.SessionFactory, I get the result below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Wgn.jpg)

in my project,only org.hibernate.hibernate-core\4.2.0.Final was included;

5.library in my project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rbAy.jpg)

6.the result of maven dependecy tree:

```html
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:3.0-alpha-1:provided
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.29:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:6.8.7:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:test
[INFO] |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.27:test
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.12:test
[INFO] +- org.unitils:unitils-core:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- ognl:ognl:jar:2.6.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.unitils:unitils-testng:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.testng:testng:jar:jdk15:5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.unitils:unitils-spring:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.unitils:unitils-orm:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.unitils:unitils-database:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.unitils:unitils-dbmaintainer:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.5.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.unitils:unitils-dbunit:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.6.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.41.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.java.dev.jna:platform:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:2.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.opera:operadriver:jar:0.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.opera:operalaunchers:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:10.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.11:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |           \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.json:json:jar:20080701:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.41.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:8.1.12.v20130726:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:compile
```

Comment: Please post screenshot of your jar files directory too..

Comment: I have add the screenshot of jar files directory above.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: Please check the response below and lets see if that goes fine.

Comment: I have altered all hibernate version to 4.3.11.Fianl, but it still display the same error as before!!

Comment: Is it okay to downgrade to hibernate 3 in your project? In that case, please try add core & entity 3.6.10.Final jar and see if you get different error.

Comment: I'm so sorry,It's not allowed in this project. And you think it's the mismatch between Spring4.2.2RELEAST and Hibernate4.2.10.Final??

Comment: As per the exception, it clearly specifies jar version mismatch. You need to verify those in your classpath and as well as in maven build.

Do the following steps:

 1. Take each and every spring/hibernate specific jar files and verify the supporting version. For example, you can find out all supporting jars for spring 4.2.2 here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.2.RELEASE
 2. Run **mvn dependency:tree** to verify dependencies in the build.

Comment: 3. Instead of **openSession()** try to use **getCurrentSession()** in your code. That is more preferred in terms of performance and bound to transaction context.    In order to use getCurrentSession(), you need to add below code into the hibernate.cfg.xml : 

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

Comment: I have run mvn dependency:tree(the result is above), and I checked the dependency jar versions are suitable in pom.xml.
In fact, in my code, HibernateTemplate is used in DAO. The OpenSessionInViewFilter defined in web.xml is in charge of Session open and closed.

Comment: And I don't know how to verify version problem in classpath [crying]

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the snaps you provided. There seems to be a mismatch in the jar file versions.

1. Your Spring version is **4.2.2.RELEASE** , you need to have 
   **Hibernate-core 4.3.11.Final** jar file. Remove Hibernate **4.2.0** and put Hibernate **4.3.11.Final** jar instead in your classpath.
2. Do the same and replace **hibernate-entitymanager** jar file to **4.3.11.Final** verison.

Hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I solved my problem by abandoning the using of HibernateTemplate but apply SessionFactory in my project to persistent data into database.
I don't know how to locate the problem.But in my mind,the reason of the problem is that HibernateTemplate is nolonger supported in Hibernate4 version.